# How to batch copy and rename files from one folder to another?

Tags: powershell, batch-file, windows-7, file-rename, batch-rename

I have 100 folders containing a psd file:

```
C:\Users\Harvey\Documents\Archive011112\TFG\SG\ET\ET2013\filenameX\psd\logo.psd
C:\Users\Harvey\Documents\Archive011112\TFG\SG\ET\ET2013\filenameY\psd\logo.psd
C:\Users\Harvey\Documents\Archive011112\TFG\SG\ET\ET2013\filenameZ\psd\logo.psd
...
```

Each psd file contains a picture:'logo.psd'

I want to copy 'logo.psd' of 'filenameX', 'filenameY', 'filenameZ' located respectively in,

```
C:\Users\Harvey\Documents\Archive011112\TFG\SG\ET\ET2013\filenameX\psd
C:\Users\Harvey\Documents\Archive011112\TFG\SG\ET\ET2013\filenameY\psd
C:\Users\Harvey\Documents\Archive011112\TFG\SG\ET\ET2013\filenameZ\psd
...
```

to another folder,

```
C:\Users\Harvey\Documents\Archive011112\TFG\SG\ET\Logos\
```

and rename 'logo' file with 'logo_parentfoldername' this way: 'logo_filenameX','logo_filenameY', 'logo_filenameZ'.

End Result:

```
C:\Users\Harvey\Documents\Archive011112\TFG\SG\ET\Logos\logo_filenameX.psd
C:\Users\Harvey\Documents\Archive011112\TFG\SG\ET\Logos\logo_filenameY.psd
C:\Users\Harvey\Documents\Archive011112\TFG\SG\ET\Logos\logo_filenameZ.psd
....
```

Hope it's clear!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick.

You want to use Get-ChildItem with -Recurse to grab all those files within each subdirectory.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $dir -Recurse
```

But filter your results to only those with the .psd extension.

```
|?{$_.Extension -eq ".psd"}
```

Then for each of those files get the name of the parent's parent directory.

```
$_.Directory.Parent.Name
```

And finally copy the file to our new file destination.

```
Copy-Item $_.FullName $copyto
```

So the end product looks something like this:

```
$dir = "C:\source\" 
$destination = "C:\destination\"

Get-ChildItem -Path $dir -Recurse | ?{$_.Extension -eq ".psd"} | % {
$copyto = $destination + $_.Directory.Parent.Name + ".psd"
Copy-Item $_.FullName $copyto 
}
```

Comment: Perfect explanation and the script worked perfectly. Some files were missing but you made my day. Many thanks again!
The only thing the file has been named with the parent folder name 'filenameX' and not 'logo_filenameX'

Comment: The file name is built in this line   
`$copyto = $destination + $_.Directory.Parent.Name + ".psd"`  

So to add "logo_" change that line to:  
`$copyto = $destination + "logo_" + $_.Directory.Parent.Name + ".psd"`

Comment: Thanks a lot, very useful information and easy to understand. Problem solved.